# Cannot use instance member 'gameModels' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available error

Tags: swift

I know this error has been discussed at least a couple of times here, but I cannot figure out what’s wrong with this code based on those answers.

I am trying to make a simple quiz app and in order the questions show up in a random order the function *private func setupQuestions() { }*, where the bank of questions was, was replaced by *let allQuestions = [ ]*, but now this error shows up on each question “Cannot use instance member 'gameModels' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available”.
Below is the code with reductions.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  
var gameModels = [Question]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // setupQuestions()
      questionsInRandomOrder
    }
  
//  private func setupQuestions() {
  
 let allQuestions = [
    gameModels.append(Question(text: "What is 2 + 2?", answers: [ 
// here comes the error Cannot use instance member 'gameModels' within property //initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
    Answer(text: "1", correct: false),
    Answer(text: "2", correct: false),
    Answer(text: "4", correct: true),
    Answer(text: "7", correct: false)
    ])),
    
    gameModels.append(Question(text: "What is 2 + 10?", answers: [
// Cannot use instance member 'gameModels' within property initializer; property //initializers run before 'self' is available
    Answer(text: "1", correct: false),
    Answer(text: "12", correct: true),
    Answer(text: "4", correct: false),
    Answer(text: "7", correct: false)
    ])),
    
    gameModels.append(Question(text: "What is 2 + 0?", answers: [
// Cannot use instance member 'gameModels' within property initializer; property //initializers run before 'self' is available
    Answer(text: "1", correct: false),
    Answer(text: "5", correct: false),
    Answer(text: "4", correct: false),
    Answer(text: "2", correct: true)
    ]))
  ]

  let questionsInRandomOrder = allQuestions.shuffled()
    
  struct Question {
    let text: String
    let answers: [Answer]
  }
  
  struct Answer {
    let text: String
    let correct: Bool // true/false
  }

}
```

Comment: Your commented-out code `func setupQuestions()` is the solution. Code affecting multiple properties depending on each other must be inside a method (or be declared `lazy`).

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. The reason I had to replace _func setupQuestions()_ with _let allQuestions = [ ]_ is because under _func setupQuestions()_ all the questions show up in the same fixed order, not randomly. If you declare allQuestions with lazy var instead of let, a fatal error occurs.

Comment: If you want a random order [`shuffle()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994753-shuffle) the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a property before class initialization thats why you are getting this error. At the comments said , take that `allQuestions` in a function or change property declaration as `lazy var` instead of `let`

At the docs:

> Lazy properties are useful when the initial value for a property is
> dependent on outside factors whose values aren’t known until after an
> instance’s initialization is complete

Comment: Thanks a lot. The thing is I cannot use `func setupQuestions()` as I need all questions appear randomly. Maybe this my comment seems stupid, but as for property declaration, when I put it `lazy var allQuestions = []`, this error under question is solved, but a fatal error shows up in another place:  
`var gameModels = [Question]()
 configureUI(question: gameModels.first!) //Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. 
  private func configureUI(question: Question) {
    label.text = question.text
    currentQuestion = question
    table.reloadData()
  }`